# How to get the most recent date from dates column from MySQL using "Thymeleaf"?

Tags: sql, database, jpa, thymeleaf

How to use Thymeleaf(not sql query if possible) and get the most recent date if subject == 'Reading'?

```
id  dates        subject 
1   2022-10-02   Reading
2   2022-10-03   Reading
3   2022-10-02   Reading
4   2022-10-02   Writing
5   2022-10-03   Reading
6   2022-10-03   Writing
```

for example i am trying to do that

```
th:if="${meeting.subject=='Reading'}"
```

and i would like to add another condition to get the latest date of the reading meetings

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do this in Java, so that the object (or one of the objects) you pass to your Thymeleaf template already knows what the max. date is for each subject.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - here's some untested sql:

```
SELECT subject, Max(dates)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE subject = "READING"
GROUP BY SUBJECT
```

Comment: is there any way i can do it using thymeleaf and not a query?

Comment: thymeleaf - i don't know this one - but surely there's a max function, or some ability to group data?